# Xcode for server client development

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

Can Xcode be used to develop in Client/Server environment. By that i mean, source code is in once location and multiple people can work on the same project without having to have multiple un-synced copies.

Much like we can do with DreamWeaver. We establish sites and the source is in single location (server), and "clients" 1) lock the file, 2) update the file, 3) post the changes, 4) revoke the lock. This way the changes are visible to every connected client.

I know Subversion can be used, but i was just wondering if Xcode has some hidden capabilities (that i don't know of). I haven't used Xcode that much.

Hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is exactly the solution to your question. You don't need a hidden capability. The process is almost identical to what you posted:

1. Update the working copy
2. Lock the file
3. Update the file
4. Commit the changes

That said, it is a very limited way to develop, since it mandates that two people can never work on the same file at the same time. For websites that might make sense (especially very complex ones), but if you're developing software, parallel development is a powerful tool and it's not clear why you'd abandon it. Is there a deeper problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to solve any deeper problems here. Was just wondering if there is a way to avoid integration of code (manually) or using Subversion for version control. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot, and that also sounds like a horrible idea. If you're a big fan of pair programming or something you can try SubEthaEdit.

Comment: Well, i don't know about this being a horrible idea, since in large projects, the development teams work on separate modules... so it makes sense to keep the code integrated and in one place, since this saves integration time.